# Kendo Angular 2 Grid Filter not available

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using the Kendo Grid with Angular 2 using this http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/ tutorial but I didn't find filtering in the grid. How can I filter my Kendo Grid with Angular 2?

Comment: If you need an alternative, checkout PrimeNG DataTable with Filtering http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter

Answer (score 5):

**Filters are not available in current Beta.0 version of kendo-angular2-grid.**

At present, you can use limited API which are listed [here](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/)

Issue is already reported on telerik's kendo-angular2. [Refer this](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/43)

Comment from Telerik member on this filter issue-

> We don't have a concrete timeline for the grid filtering feature.
>   There are a number of prerequisites of this feature, the most
>   significant one being the date pickers. You can review our roadmap for
>   further details - http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/roadmap/

This idea is already posted on newly opened feedback portal [Refer this](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-feedback/suggestions/16652602-grid-filtering-like-kendo-angular-1-grid)

Answer (score 5):

I created this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qdJIkLbryTg2qoNcHOMR?p=preview) where you can filter your grid by product Name. It's a very basic example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {
  GridDataResult,
  SortDescriptor,
  orderBy
} from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter" (ngModelChange)="change()">
      <kendo-grid
          [data]="gridView"
          [sortable]="{ mode: 'multiple' }"
          [sort]="sort"
          (sortChange)="sortChange($event)"
        >
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" width="120">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" width="230">
        </kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    private filter: string;
    private sort: SortDescriptor[] = [];
    private gridView: GridDataResult;
    private products: any[] = [
      {
        "ProductID": 1,
        "ProductName": "Chai",
        "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
        "Discontinued": false
    },
       {
        "ProductID": 3,
        "ProductName": "Chai",
        "UnitPrice": 122.0000,
        "Discontinued": true
    }
                               ,{
        "ProductID": 2,
        "ProductName": "Chang",
        "UnitPrice": 19.0000,
        "Discontinued": false
    }];

    constructor() {
        this.loadProducts();
    }

    protected sortChange(sort: SortDescriptor[]): void {
        this.sort = sort;
        this.loadProducts();
    }

    private loadProducts(prods): void {
      const products = prods || this.products;
        this.gridView = {
            data: orderBy(products, this.sort),
            total: products.length
        };
    }

   private change(){
      this.loadProducts(this.products.filter(product => product.ProductName === this.filter));
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @fabio  for the plunker demo. I am expecting the Kendo Grid in built filter like they have given in there kendo grid demo http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-row.

Comment: @user2924558 well as Sanket said that's not implemented yet

Comment: Thanks, this is what is seek for. Because there is no official implementation yet. This would be great!

Answer (score 5):

I was just checking possible ways to enable filter in Kendo Angular 2 Grid and found that Telerik has enabled it. Please check following link.

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/

Answer (score 0):

i added to the Fabio Antunes solution
Import compileFilter from '@progress/kendo-data-query';

and change the change() method to the following.  This will allow you to filter by multiple columns.  Again not exactly what i want, but this will do for now.

```
const predicate = compileFilter({
            logic: "and",
            filters: [
                { field: "fildname1", operator: "contains", value: this.filterValue },
                { field: "fildname2", operator: "contains", value: this.filterValue },
                { field: "fildname3", operator: "eq", value: this.filterValue },
                { field: "fildname4", operator: "eq", value: this.filterValue },
            ]
        });
        const result = this.data.filter(predicate);
        this.gridView = {
            data: result,
            total: result.length
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Update on the Kendo filter - Very similar to Nonik's solution.

Replace "compileFilter" with "filterBy".  This is part of the dataquery set of helper functions.

```
import { filterBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query'
```

[Kendo Data Query](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/)

Answer (score 0):

For your information Kendo Grid has add filter feature in latest version. Please look at their website.

If you stll required some custome filter with kendo grid in angular 2 then look at here or search in google : Angular-2 + Kendo Grid Custom Filter