# Kendo Grid for Angular 2 Features

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am currently trying to move from Angular 1.5 to Angular 2 and we are using Kendo Grid features extensively. I have a list of features which I need for converting to Angular 2 -

1. Multi Column Headers and Column Filters (available in Kendo-UI for Angular 1 through ColumnMenu -> Columns). Not available - [Multi Column Header for Angular 2 Kendo Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742474/multi-column-header-for-angular-2-kendo-grid/40742598#40742598)
2. Data Filters for Columns(available in Kendo-UI for Angular 1 through ColumnMenu -> Filter). Not available - [Kendo Angular 2 Grid Filter not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920644/kendo-angular-2-grid-filter-not-available)
3. Exporting to Excel (available in Kendo-UI for Angular 1 through toolbars). Not Available - [Kendo UI Angular 2 Grid Excel Export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910539/kendo-ui-angular-2-grid-excel-export)

The question is, is there any place/table which lists all the features of the Kendo-Grid for Angular 1 and lists whether it is available in Kendo for Angular 2 and if not, which release is it planned in. The roadmap is not very clear on when these features are planned to be released and what features will be available in the Jan/May release.

This would be very helpful in deciding whether to move to Kendo for Angular 2 or not.

Thanks

Comment: All of the mentioned features are on our immediate plans due to their popularity. They should land in the Jan-May timeframe. Note that we're releasing the packages continuously as fixes and features become available.

Answer (score 0):

All this functionality is about to be implemented in the Angular 2 suite. You can [log missing features on UserVoice](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-feedback/category/181393-grid), so that you'll be updated on the planning and implementation status.

Comment: All these features will be available in the January 18th 2017 release?

Comment: The current focus is on delivering grid editing, and features will be prioritized based on feedback after this. Log feature requests to receive notifications about what is planned.